# Strange warning/error when working with polygons

Tags: geopandas, shapely, numpy

Reading a polygon shapefile with geopandas I got a strange error. I found out it is a normally hidden warning about another error, which I saw only because I turned warnings to errors. It also appears when creating a GeoDataFrame:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import random

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')

geoms = [Polygon(
    (random.random(), random.random())
        for p in range(10)) for id in range(10)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 300, in __array_interface__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: A polygon does not itself provide the array interface. Its rings do.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 11, in <module>
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 167, in __init__
    self.set_geometry(geometry, inplace=True)
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 295, in set_geometry
    level = _ensure_geometry(level, crs=crs)
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 43, in _ensure_geometry
    out = from_shapely(data, crs=crs)
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py", line 168, in from_shapely
    return GeometryArray(vectorized.from_shapely(data), crs=crs)
  File "C:\Daten2\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_vectorized.py", line 142, in from_shapely
    aout[:] = out
DeprecationWarning: An exception was ignored while fetching the attribute `__array_interface__` from an object of type 'Polygon'.  With the exception of `AttributeError` NumPy will always raise this exception in the future.  Raise this deprecation warning to see the original exception. (Warning added NumPy 1.21)
```

The warning occurs in the line

```
aout[:] = out
```

of a geopandas module. out is a list of shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon, while aout is a numpy array of the same length with dtype object, containing Nones.

So I'm curious what is happening here?

Comment: Show us more code. What does the function `pm` does? Excerpt plz. Your issue may be Python scope related. Very difficult or impossible to guess from current provided infos as too incomplete

Comment: Based on your comment *'The same instruction, same file, typed at the python prompt successfully..'* leads me to suspect you may have multiple python environments installed ..and the interpreter you're entering manually is somehow different from the interpreter your entering via your scripted solution.

Comment: You might try this in both your Python prompt and your script and compare the output: `import sys` (then next line) `print(sys.executable)` ..if they give you different results, it means you need to specify the interpreter you're using in your scripted environment.

Comment: @ThomasG77 pdb.pm() is the post mortem debugger from the standard library. Yes, I will try to create a minimum reproducible program, but I fear that's no easy task.

Comment: @elrobis I call both prompt and program from the conda command prompt with activated base environment. The program with `cd C:\Daten2\G991` `python -i g991edat.py`. I checked sys.executable, sys.path and os.environment and can't detect any difference.

Comment: Ah, I forgot in my program I turn warnings in errors (`warnings.filterwarnings('error')`), this answers most of my question. I still find this a strange result, will provide self-contained code later.

Comment: Also having this issue - it's not seeming to break anything and comes in a recent version of numpy (1.21).

Comment: I'm having it as well.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an error on user side. It is the result of a recent change in Numpy 1.21 coupled with a way shapely implements (rather not implements) `__array_interface__`. There is nothing the user should do, it will be fixed in the next release of shapely (see https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/pull/1174). You can silence these warnings if you want and keep an eye on the issue.

Comment: I updated shapely and the warning was gone! Thanks for the constructive discussion!

Comment: i was trying to follow the thread you posted but am still confused. i think my issue and this one are related but not the same. i'm also getting the same warning when creating a geodataframe with geometry = geopandas.points_from_xy(xx, yy) [i guess more accurately the issue is the points_from_xy call?]. i get the warning both where xx and yy are pandas geoseries or numpy arrays. but i'm not using numpy 1.21 (using np 1.19.5; shapely 1.8; geopandas 0.9). any ideas?

Comment: @user20408 I would first try using the latest version of geopandas (0.10.2).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error. I used `conda install -c conda-forge shapely` to install shapely but it only gave me 1.7.1 version. So I upgraded it manually `pip install Shapely==1.8.2` and the error disappeared.